# Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES' in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

My app supports only landscape mode. when i am trying to open image picker within the app it shows an exception which is as follows:
"Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES" 
I had tried to make false value for shouldAutorotate but didn't succeed. I am stuck with this. Any one have any help regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use UIImagePickerController as lanndscape mode , instead of

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return NO;
}
```

use this

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

but make sure to check this as:

[image]